# Using arguments in Selenium Java on Xpath Expression

Tags: java, selenium

I want to use the argument 'option' as part of the findElement by the Xpath Expression:

```
 public HomePage clickSizeOption (String option){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("span[contains(@class, 'checkmark') and text()= option]")).click();
        return this;
    }
```

But java treats the entire by xpath as a string.

HTML Context:

[image: I need to select XS only but that would have to be from the argument]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the format() method for this. I also noticed your xpath doesn't start with '//'.
Afaik an xpath should always start with '//' except if you start from the html element.

Try this out

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//span[contains(@class, 'checkmark') and text()= %s]", option)).click();
```